# Windows Azure Storage and Computer servers don't start

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I've been working on an Azure application. Everything has been good for a long time until I just had my VS2010 instance hang. I restarted the computer and now notice that when I debug locally then the compute and storage emulators don't attempt to start. I just goes straight to the application which fails very quick.

When I start them manually then everything works.

Is there a place where the emulators are set to run on start up? I seem to remember seeing some setting but cannot find it now.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "just goes straight to the application which fails very quick" ? What actually happens, and how does it fail? Also, what are you starting manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the emulators running with the correct instance you can select Debug > Start without debugging. This will start the site at 127.0.0.1:81 (or some other port) and also run the emulators in one go.

If you are running this through IIS rather than the localhost 127.0.0.1 you may need to recycle your application pool so it can reflect the new instance after the step above. Although this feels a bit fiddly it is the most reliable way I found.

I wrote a blog post on [getting your azure emulators running](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/09/not-running-in-hosted-service-or.html) properly if you want more details.